Data extension retrieval is not working - ssjs
A simple code to retrieve data extension details is not working. It's giving undefined values.
Here's the code :
 <script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

    try {
        // Simple test to check if SSJS is working
        Write("SSJS environment is functioning.<br>");
        
        // Define Data Extension Name
        var deName = " XXXXX ";
        
        // Attempt to initialize Data Extension
        var de = DataExtension.Init(deName);

        // Print details if Data Extension exists
        if (de) {
            Write("Data Extension Name: " + de.Name + "<br>");
            Write("Data Extension Description: " + de.Description + "<br>");
            Write("Data Extension Status: " + de.Status + "<br>");
        } else {
            Write("Data Extension not found.<br>");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        Write("Error: " + Stringify(error) + "<br>");
    }
</script>


You would need to use the Retrieve function.
You can try something like this:
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core", "1.1.1");

// Simple test to check if SSJS is working
Write("SSJS environment is functioning.<br>");

// Define Data Extension Customer Key
var DEcustKey = "Your DE customer key";

// Attempt to initialize Data Extension
var results = DataExtension.Retrieve({Property:"CustomerKey",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value: DEcustKey});

// Print details if Data Extension exists
if (results.length> 0) {
    Write("Data Extension Name: " + results[0].Name + "<br>");
    Write("Data Extension Description: " + results[0].Description + "<br>");
    Write("Data Extension Status: " + results[0].Status + "<br>");
} else {
    Write("Data Extension not found.<br>");
}
</script>


Note: You should use your DE customer key for the filter so it can retrieve the DE with accurate results.

No, it didn't work. Got this error.
'Error Message: "CreateObject Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in non sendable content. Function: CreateObject("RetrieveRequest")"
Description: "ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: CreateObject Function is not valid in content. This function is only allowed in non sendable content. Function: CreateObject("RetrieveRequest") Error Code: OMM_FUNC_CONTEXT_ERR - from Jint "'

@DrishtiJindal Have you tried to run it on a Cloudpage?

Yes, i am running it in cloud page only.

is the cloudpage published or are you checking out the preview? Because the preview is considered "sendable context", the published page is not.

@DrishtiJindal like Jonas have said, you need to publish the cloud page and go there to check

You can refer to the below document to retrieve the Data from Dataextension. Please find the revised code. I hope this will work
https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/contact-builder/records/retrieve/
<script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1");

    try {

        var customerKey = {{Dataextension external Key}};

        var de = DataExtension.Init(customerKey);

        var result = de.Rows.Retrieve({
            Property: "Status", 
            SimpleOperator: "isNotNull", 
            Value: " " 
        });

        Write(Stringify(result));
        
    } catch(error) {
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }   

</script>


Error:
{"message":"Object expected: Retrieve","jintException":"Jint.Native.JsException: Exception of type 'Jint.Native.JsException' was thrown.\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MethodCall methodCall)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MethodCall.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(MemberExpression expression)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.MemberExpression.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(VariableDeclarationStatement statement)\r\n at Jint.Expressions.VariableDeclarationStatement.Accept(IJintVisitor visitor)\r\n at Jint.ExecutionVisitor.Visit(BlockSt

Strange @DrishtiJindal, this worked for me and able to retrieve the data. Few clarification 1. You are using the dataextension external key? 2. Does your dataextension has 'Status' column?

My DE name and external key is same, so i used that. Also, i modified the search based on my column value but it didn't work.

You might need to publish the page, then copy the Cloud Page URL and paste it into your browser. If you encounter an error during publishing, you can disregard it until you see the same error in the browser.
